# Postgresql trigger fails when using IF ELSE

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have this piece of code (which actually works):

```
    CREATE or replace FUNCTION checkRank() RETURNS trigger AS $checkRank$

    DECLARE
    old_rank varChar;
    old_date date;

    BEGIN 

--  SELECT a.rank INTO old_rank from RANK a where a.account = new.account;
    SELECT a.rank, a.date INTO old_rank, old_date from RANK a where a.account = new.account order by date desc LIMIT 1;

        -- Check if inserted rank != current rank           
        if old_rank = new.rank THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'rank unchanged';
        END IF;
                if new.date < old_date THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'old rank';
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END
$checkRank$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

which actually fails when I use an IF ELSE instead:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION checkRank() RETURNS trigger AS $checkRank$

    DECLARE
    old_rank varChar;
    old_date date;

    BEGIN 

--  SELECT a.rank INTO old_rank from RANK a where a.account = new.account;
    SELECT a.rank, a.date INTO old_rank, old_date from RANK a where a.account = new.account order by date desc LIMIT 1;

        -- Check if inserted rank != current rank           
        IF old_rank = new.rank THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'rank unchanged';
        ELSE IF new.date < old_date THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'old rank';
        ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END
$checkRank$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

with the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
>
> LINE 21: $checkRank$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Anyone has a clue what's going wrong, I can't figure it out with Google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSE IF`:

```
IF old_rank = new.rank THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'rank unchanged';
ELSIF new.date < old_date THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'old rank';
ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
END IF;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=38e9944371cfa286f5fae7a9d0269273)**

---

> [41.6.2. Conditionals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)
>
> PL/pgSQL has three forms of IF:
>
> - IF ... THEN ... END IF
> - IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF
> - **IF ... THEN ... ELSIF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF**